# Win2D with WinForms

Tags: winforms, graphics, directx, win2d

Is there any way to use Win2D in WinForms application? I've searched it on the web, but there is no information...

Or if you know some alternative to Win2D can you send them to me? I need a library that is:

1. High-level
2. Gives me the ability to perform smooth animations (60+ fps). I think the library should work with DirectX

Answer (score 0):

I believe SharpDX is a good candidate: http://sharpdx.org/

> SharpDX is an open-source managed .NET wrapper of the DirectX API.